# Why do not STL algorithms deduce default value type from iterator value?

Tags: c++, stl

There are STL algorithms like `accumulate` or `inner_product` that reduce range to a scalar. Historically they all require initial value whose type can be deduced from the initial value argument, but not from the iterator argument. And that's error-prone:

```
vector<float> a;
// error: deduced type is integer, 
// and all the values are truncated up to the integer part.
auto sum = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0); 

vector<long long> a;
// error: deduced type is integer, 
// so the result can overflow.
auto sum = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
```

The standard definition could have been like

```
template< class InputIt,
          class T = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init = T {});
```

instead of the current

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init );
```

In C++17 `reduce` actually does kind of that trick

```
template<class InputIt>
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type
  reduce(InputIt first, InputIt last);
```

but only when initial value isn't here. When it's here definition stays as usually

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
T reduce(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init);
```

**Is there a particular reason for such decisions, or is it just bad design?** I'm asking, because I know that the standard made by great specialists, and feels like the answer is the former, and I just don't understand it.

Comment: Default template arguments for function templates is a feature that was added in C++11, and the specification for accumulate is older than that.

Comment: Any reason why definition of `accumulate` can't be updated?

Comment: @AlexanderSolovets Because `accumulate` has to stay backwards compatible.  People might rely on that.  E.g. somebody might accumulate a vector of doubles into an int, which works with `std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);`.  If you changed the deduction to what `std::reduce` has, the last argument would be converted to double and the function returns a double, which behaves very different from what was done before.

Comment: @HenriMenke, the proposed definition is backward-compatible, I checked it.

Comment: With your two examples, compilers can issue warnings for those conversions.  Having a different type for the default value is necessary to allow accumulating into larger types, like floats into a double or ints into a long.